# How to install libffi-dev on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, homebrew, libffi, micropython

I am trying to implement micropython on unix, which requires `libffi-dev`. I installed in this way `brew install libffi-dev`. But it seems that there is no libffi-dev can be found.

Is there any way to install `libffi-dev` on Mac os. Thank you.

Comment: Try `brew install libffi`.

Comment: If this worked you should answer the question and accept it.

Comment: @PaulR Thank you Paul. `brew install libffi` works on Mac. But I am confused that are libffi and libffi-dev the same thing?

Comment: @XiufenXu: on Linux they often separate packages into `xxx` and `xxx-dev`, where `xxx` contains the minimum you need just to use a library or whatever, while the `xxx-dev` package contains source code and other supporting files to enable you to modify and rebuild the package if needed. With Homebrew on Mac OS X you typically get all this in just one `xxx` package, so you won't normally see separate `xxx-dev` packages (although there are a few exceptions to this rule of thumb, e.g. `google-chrome` and `google-chrome-dev`).

Comment: @PaulR That's really what I want to clear up. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

On Mac OS X you just need:

```
$ brew install libffi
```

Comment: Any alternative to brew, it tends to own my python whenever I use it which equals instant regret.

Comment: @PaulKenjora: try MacPorts or even fink ?

Comment: You can look at the source to figure out what it does.

Go to https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libffi and click "Formula code: libffi.rb on GitHub".

We can see the dependencies via the `depends_on`:
1. autoconf
2. automake
3. libtool

We can then convert it to the following:

1. git clone https://github.com/libffi/libffi.git
2. `cd libffi`
3 `./autogen.sh`
4. `./configure`
5. `make install`

Homebrew shouldn't conflict with your Python, if it does you've probably installed Python via brew. You should probably be using venvs or something, it'll make your life much easier :-).

Answer (score 4):

Error:

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.7.dylib
```

The following worked (it’s not an `ln -s` but it did the trick):

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/opt/libffi
sudo mkdir /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib
sudo cp /usr/lib/libffi.dylib /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.7.dylib
```

Turns out Xcode already installs a library, it’s just not in the right spot.

Comment: Symbolic links would probably be a better approach than copying. That way you get the correct version when you update the OS.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when paramiko python library was giving file not found error ::

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.dylib /usr/local/lib/libffi.7.dylib
```