# Can't install Ruby Compass on Mac Big Sur 11.5.2

Tags: ruby, gruntjs, compass

I'm trying to get Compass installed on a 2020 Mac Book Pro running Big Sur (11.5.2).

When I try and run:

```
gem install compass
```

I get the error:

```
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory
```

If I try and run:

```
sudo gem install compass
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/ext/ffi_c
```

I've tried installing and updating Ruby.
I've tried updating the system Ruby, but the system doesn't allow a more recent version than the below:

```
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching rubygems-update-3.3.3.gem
Successfully installed rubygems-update-3.3.3
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-3.3.3
Installing ri documentation for rubygems-update-3.3.3
Installing darkfish documentation for rubygems-update-3.3.3
Done installing documentation for rubygems-update after 206 seconds
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-3.3.3
Done installing documentation for rubygems-update after 0 seconds
Installing RubyGems 3.3.3
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted @ rb_sysopen - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/gem

 % ruby -v
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
```

Not sure what to do or try next.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get Compass installed?

Comment: First, it's uncommon to install gems with sudo. Many rubyists avoid using the system (OS) ruby for this reason, instead using a ruby version manager like `rbenv`. You might try that, or you could focus on why ffi doesn't install. What error does `sudo gem install ffi -v "1.15.4"` produce?

Comment: Do you have the developer tools installed?

Comment: @JaredBeck I get the error:
`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.`

Comment: @pjs I believe I do. If I enter `xcode-select --install` the response says command line tools are already installed  - is that what you meant?

Comment: Also, please note that the `compass` seems to no longer be maintained: https://github.com/Compass/compass. I'd switch to a different library, though I do sympathize with you if that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really decomposes to two issues, as you noticed with the `sudo` call.

(1) You're trying to write gems to the protected directory for your system Ruby.

In most development environments, it's best to install a Ruby version manager that allows you to install multiple Rubies side-by-side for different projects. Purely subjectively, I'd recommend `rbenv` to manage *only* Ruby, or `asdf` to manage Ruby versions along with other languages versions. However, the question of which Ruby version manager to use is [very well tread already](https://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-version-managers-macos/), so you can pick the solution that's best for your needs with existing information.

(2) You're installing a gem with native extensions, which means that you need the underlying C libraries installed on your system to build correctly (assuming you're using CRuby, the default Ruby implementation). You'll need to install `libffi-dev` on your machine to build that gem correctly. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706311/how-to-install-libffi-dev-on-mac-os-x), it seems a simple `brew install libffi` should work for that.

Lastly, I'll suggest that it's idiomatic to use the [`bundler` gem](https://bundler.io/) to manage gems per-project with Ruby. I'd reconsider if you really want to run this gem system-wide, or if it might vary versions across multiple projects.

Comment: Thank you. Using `rbenv` worked for me. Speficially using the shell command to switch to a local version of ruby. Then install Compass using `gem install compass`. Just incase anyone else is looking for the same solution. `libffi` wouldn't install because of the same protected system 2.6 version of Ruby.